# OAuth 2 Callback URL

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I need to use OAuth2 to connect to server. But I cannot understand that I need to put into the callback URL in the server settings if I want used it in my Android app. I know that I can read it in specs but I cannot understand their. Please, explain it for me easier. Just I cannot find information in Russian and English specs are very difficult.